# Cannot list contents of db file in Xamarin

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mono

I want to create an easy quiz application that gets values from a .db file.

In my MainPage.xaml.cs I want to list all my questions (with just one answer option for testing,  from a database that is embedded and is implemented correctly for both platforms) in a list form just for now, but I get a white empty stuff without any error msg.

DataModels/Questions.cs

```
namespace quiztest.DataModels
{ 
    public class Questions
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Field{ get; set; }
        public string Question{ get; set; }
        public string Answer1 { get; set; }
        public string Answer2 { get; set; }
        public string Answer3 { get; set; }
        public string Answer4 { get; set; }
        public string CorrectAnswer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using quiztest.DataModels;

...
    
protected override void OnAppearing()
            {
                base.OnAppearing();
                using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.FilePath))
                {
                    var questions = conn.Table<Question>().ToList();
                    quizListView.ItemsSource = questions;
    
    
                }
    
            }
```

MainPage.Xaml

```
        <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Contents:"/>
        <Label x:Name="labelrandom"/>
        <ScrollView>
            <ListView x:Name="quizListView">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding Question}" Detail="{Binding Answer1}" TextColor="Aquamarine"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>
```

I feel that the issue is related to getting the correct columns to show up on the textcell but I am just started learning and I am not an expert.

Comment: "from a database that is embedded and is implemented correctly" - are you positive about this?  The fact that you are not getting any results would indicate that you haven't done it correctly.  How many items are in `questions` after you run your query?

Comment: the .db file has a Questions Table that has all the columns it was provided by the teacher (so I guess that is correct), how can I check the item amount while running the query?

Comment: Put a breakpoint after the query and use the debugger, or use `Console.Writeline` to output the count.  How exactly are you including the db in your app?  Do you need to write to the db, or is it read-only?

Comment: I checked and for some strange reason i cannot ad breakpoint to anywhere in my codes (visual studio glitch?), and I couldn't find the console.writeline debug in output, so that is an issue I guess?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
var questions = conn.Table<Question>().ToList();
quizListView.ItemsSource = questions;
```

with

```
 var questions = (from x in conn.Table<Question>() select x).ToList();  
 quizListView.ItemsSource = questions ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, however the listview is empty and I am not getting any results. The .db file has one Table that has Question and four Answer columns (according to DB explorer), can you recommend any other steps?

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use collectionview instead.
to fix your problem bind the listview to a observablecollention

```
 private ObservableCollection<Questions> questionsList;
        public ObservableCollection<Questions> QuestionsList
        {
            get { return questionsList; }
            set
            {
                if (questionsList != value)
                {
                    questionsList = value;
                  
                }
            }
        }
```

then in your Function :

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
            {
                base.OnAppearing();

               string dbPath = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString(), dbName);
                var db = new SQLiteConnection (dbPath);
                     var quesList = db.Table<Questions>().toList();
                    QuestionsList = new ObservableCollection<Questions>(quesList);
                    quizListView.ItemsSource = QuestionsList;
    
    
                }
    
            }
```

or you can bind it Directly to the listview

```
<ListView x:Name="quizListView" ItemsSource={Binding QuestionsList}>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding Question}" Detail="{Binding Answer1}" TextColor="Aquamarine"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help however, I still don't have any value to show up (white emptiness) without any error code.

Comment: @DroidDeveloper027 can you please check if there is available data in db and its returning in the line code                      var quesList = (from x in conn.Table<Question>() select x).ToList();

Comment: the DB file seems fine, I opened it with DB browser and it has the correct table name, and data (it was provided by the lecturer in .db and . sqlite file), but sadly I don't get any result even after digging 72 hours on this topic only.

Comment: dear @DroidDeveloper027. please answer my question. are you retrieving the data from the data base in the line var questions = conn.Table<Question>().ToList(); , Or no. Please put a break point in your code at this line and see if questions list is being populated or no.

Comment: Sorry, No, it seems that I am not retrieving data.

Comment: try my edited code and make sure you enter the right filepath to the db

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create the connection in App.cs with code like:
static NoteDatabase database;

```
// Create the database connection as a singleton.
public static MyDatabase Database
{
    get
    {
        if (database == null)
        {
            database = new MyDatabase(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "dbfile.db3"));
        }
        return database;
    }
}
```

and set the itemssource in onappearing.

You can refer to this sample to understand better:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/getstarted-notes-database/

Comment: Thank you, but as far as I know I already did implement the filepath in App.cs (CODE: public static string FilePath;
        public App(string filePath)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new MainPage();

            FilePath = filePath;
        } CODE ENDS)